# how to prevent a react calculator from beginning with multiple zeros

Tags: reactjs

I have a react calculator displaying zero when nothing has been input yet. I want to prevent the calculator from ever allowing two zeros at the beginning of a number. Right now, my calculator will remove two zeros at the beginning of a number after they show up on the display. But it will not prevent it from happening in the first place.

I have tried checking for zero at the beginning of array state and resetting the state to just one zero.

```
    class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);

      this.state = {
      //result: '0'
      result: ['0'],
     }
    };
    addToInput = (param, e) => {

    let arrayLength = this.state.result.length;
    if (param === "0" && arrayLength < 2) {
      this.setState({ result: 0 })
    } else {
      this.setState({ result: this.state.result + param });
    }
  }
    render() {
    return (
    ...
    <div id="zero" className="btn" onClick={(e) => this.addToInput('0', 
 e)}> 0</div >
    ...
    )
    }
    }
```

I want to prevent two leading zeros from appearing but I am just able to remove one zero after two leading zeros do appear.

Comment: Is `result` an array, a string, or a number? Because you declare it as an array, but later re-assign it to simply a number. `result: 0` is setting it to simply a number, but also you're simply setting it to a string when you do `['0'] + '2'`, which effectively sets it to `'02'`. So, you need to clean that up. Also, if you ever need to reference the previous state, then you MUST to it in a callback, as state changes are not performed immediately. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate Your question is unanswerable with the ambiguity of what `result` is supposed to be.

Comment: I made result a string ' '  and everything that updates it to a string and the code works without any other changes. I have been using vue and I am now learning react. I will study the docs about updating state if you need to reference previous state. Thank you.

Comment: That’s great! Glad I could help.